# Flutter workmanger with sqlite

Tags: flutter, dart, background, flutter-dependencies

I'm building a finance app using flutter and flutter_drift for SQLite database and workmanger for background tasks.

Now I need a way to run an insert query in the background even if the app is closed every while like day/week/month.

I tried what below but throws an error that I have called `AppDatabase` class multiple time which is true as I can't get the database class instance from the main isolate using `getIt`

What I have done so far in code:

```dart
void callbackDispatcher() {
  configureInjection(Environment.prod);

  final ITransactionService transactionService = TransactionService(
    TransactionRepository(TransactionsDao(AppDatabase())),
    ContactPickerService(),
    ImagePickerService(),
  );

  Workmanager().executeTask(
    (task, inputData) async {
      switch (task) {
        case 'repeatedTransaction':
          // final String tId = inputData['string'];
          final String? id = inputData?['string'];

          optionOf(id).fold(
            () => null,
            (id) async {
              final Either<TransactionFailure, TransactionDomain?> t =
                  await transactionService.findTransactionById(id);

              t.fold(
                (l) => print('$l'),
                (transactionDomain) {
                  if (transactionDomain != null) {
                    transactionService.create(transactionDomain.copyWith(
                        date: TransactionDate(DateTime.now())));
                  }
                },
              );
            },
          );

          break;
        default:
      } //simpleTask will be emitted here.
      return Future.value(true);
    },
  );
}
```